# python urllib - send an #input text in header and submit it

Tags: python, html, url, urllib

I'm trying to access a website and give a certain value to an input on the website.

The input has the form of :

```
<input id="wavelength" name="wavelength" style="width:80pt;" 
onchange="nk(false),reflection(true),transmission(false)">
<input id="wavelength_submit" type="submit" class="noprint" value="↵" 
onclick="nk(false),reflection(true),transmission(false)">
```

I'm fairely new to this, but I know you can ask for a specific variable to have a specific value.

What I'm requesting is:

```
url = 'https://refractiveindex.info'
values = {'shelf': 'glass', 'book': axicon_material, 'wavelength':  used_wavelength, 'wavelength_submit': 'true'}
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('utf-8')

index_mainpage_request = urllib.request.Request(url,data)
index_mainpage_response = urllib.request.urlopen(index_mainpage_request)
paragraphs = re.findall(r'<p>(.*?)</p>', str(index_mainpage_response.read()))
```

The input box on the website however, doesn't want to change its content. Is there a way I can do that from my request? Because this way doesn't seem to work

Comment: I’ll look it up, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium is the package I was looking for. But There is and headless format with phantomJS, exactly what I wanted.

Still, I think there would be better ways to fetch information from a website database rather than interfacing it.